# Literally displaying imported cells with <HTML> and <BODY> tags

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am importing some data from MS-SQL 2005 into excel sheet (2007) using classic ASP. The code snippet headers are

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & filename & ".xls"
```

Some fields out of the imported data has HTML contents "", ", "" etc which in turn ms-excel formats as HTML and show me images and other html contents are also formatted while opening excel sheet.

**I want excel to treat all html tags as unformatted text.**

Your help in this context will be highly appreciated.

Note: I have been through many similar questions but couldn't found any clue to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: You could try prefixing the field values with `'`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing the tag's < and > with the html entities, like so?

```
Replace(Replace(somedata,"<","&lt;"),">","&gt;")
```

Comment: But I need "<" instead of "&lt;" because we use the excel sheet in eBay File Exchange where we must have actual html entities to produce the desired result.

Comment: _I want excel to treat all html tags as unformatted text._   I don't understand your goal.